# Disable click on Slider Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to replicate this type of functionality using React and Material UI components:

https://codepen.io/imoskvin/pen/yOXqvO?editors=0010

```
..
..
..
..
```

I decided to go with the Slider Component from Material UI to help me with this and this is the code I have so far:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-jb2bw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

However, the functionality of clicking to advance the Slider is still included and I would like to disable this. Is there anyway I can do this easily? I checked and there does not seem to be a prop for this according to the docs. If anyone could help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

https://material-ui.com/components/slider/